# Remove grey background confidence interval from forecasting plot

Tags: r

I created the forecasting plot with the point forecast and confidence interval. However, i only want the point forecast(blue line) without the confidence interval(the grey background). How do i do that? Below is my current code and the screenshot of my plot.

```
  plot(snv.data$mean,main="Forecast for monthly Turnover in Food   
  Retailing",xlab="Years",ylab="$ million",+ geom_smooth(se=FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 23):

Currently it seems to me that you try a mixture between the `base` function `plot` and the `ggplot2` function `geom_smooth`. I don't think it is a very good idea in this case.

Since you want to use geom_smooth why not try to do it all with `ggplot2'?

Here is how you would do it with `ggplot2` ( I used R-included airmiles data as example data)

```
library(ggplot2)
data = data.frame("Years"=seq(1937,1960,1),"Miles"=airmiles) #Creating a sample dataset

ggplot(data,aes(x=Years,y=Miles))+ 
        geom_point()+ 
        geom_smooth(se=F)
```

With `ggplot` you can set options like your x and y variables once and for all in the `aes()` of your `ggplot()` call, which is the reason why I didnt need any `aes()` call for `geom_point()`.

Then I add the smoother function `geom_smooth()`, with option `se=F` to remove the confidence interval